# Migration text is outdated

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

Currently the migration text(shown below) references the old name(PPCG) of this site.
[image: Migration Text]

Since this site is now called Code  Golf & Coding Challenges, shouldn't we change the migration text to reference that instead?

Comment: Where are you seeing the old name?  The url is correct and the description is still accurate.

Comment: I don't see "PPCG" or "Programming Puzzles and Code Golf" anywhere.

Comment: **programming puzzle** enthusiasts and **code golfers**

Comment: Are we now _code golfers and coding challengers_?

Comment: I see this as pretty low priority but I don't understand the downvotes. If anyone actively objects to the wording being changed, it would be good to see an answer justifying this, to get a wider discussion

Comment: Due to UI changes, this isn't an issue anymore, so I've marked it as complete.

Answer (score 5):

This is far from a big problem but I'd still like to see it tidied up. We could request this be changed to

> This question came from our site for code golfers and coding challenge enthusiasts

If you agree the wording should change but prefer a different wording to this suggestion, post it as a separate answer so the community can discuss and vote.

Comment: +1 from me; I think this wording resembles the name of the website and the meaning of the migration message well